# VBNet: List of items inside a class, I cant change the value for a single item

Tags: arrays, list, class, properties

My Problem:
I have a Class and a list of other class inside:

```
Public Class Signal_Type_Read

    Private c_signal_count As Integer = 0  ' counter for read signals
    Private _items As List(Of Signal_Item)
    Private item As New Signal_Item

    Sub add_sig()
        c_signal_count += 1
        items.Add(item)
    End Sub
    Public Property items() As List(Of Signal_Item)
        Get
            Return _items
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Signal_Item))
            _items = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Function item_counter() As Integer
        item_counter = c_signal_count
    End Function
    Public Sub New()
        _items = New List(Of Signal_Item)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Signal_Item


    Private _original_name As String

    Public Property Original_name() As String
        Get
            Return _original_name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _original_name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Many other properties
End Class
```

My problem is when I use in a loop

```
Public Shared ReadSignals As New Signal_Type_Read 

//Part of a Loop to read cells values and store in the variable
ReadSignals.add_sig()
Dim c_index As Integer = ReadSignals.item_counter - 1                   
ReadSignals.items.item(c_index).Original_name = c_row.Cells(e_Signame).Value
```

It always changes the "Original_name" Property in all items of my Variable. Where is my error? I want only that oe item is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem... I need to create a new instane of item in my ADD_sig() sub

```
 Sub add_sig()
    Dim s_item As New Signal_Item
    c_signal_count += 1
    items.Add(s_item)
End Sub
```